# HTACCESS Rewrite URL Error

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a project and using .htaccess to rewrite URLs.

My file uploader uploads files to a directory called 'u'.

So for example, if I upload 'textfile.txt', it will go to 'u/textfile.txt'

My problem is, that I use htaccess to rewrite the URL so you can go to:

`u/textfile`

And it will display the info of the 'u/textfile.txt' and the contents of the file inside that page, the only thing is that I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is my .htaccess code:

`RewriteRule ^u/(.*)(\.)(.*)$ u/$1(\.)$2 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^u/(.*)(\/?)$ upload.php?hash=$1 [L,NE]`

What I want is:

People to be able to go to -
u/1.2 (1 = name of file, 2 = file extension)
u/1 (1 = name of file)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This rule is causing problem and infinite looping for you:

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)(\.)(.*)$ u/$1(\.)$2 [L]
```

Change this to:

```
RewriteRule ^u/([^.]+)/?$ /u/$1.txt [L,NC]
```

Comment: Half way there, thanks!

I miswrote the question, I want people to be able to go to

u/1.2 (1 = name of file, 2 = file extension)
u/1 (1 = name of file)

Comment: Using my suggested answer your visitors can open: `/u/textfile.txt` OR `/u/textfile`

Comment: Yes, however, the .txt can change to something like .png or .gif so the rule would have to change I think. I tried to modify it myself but I got an error.

Comment: That's a problem because if user enters this URL: `/u/textfile` then how will .htaccess know whether to append `.txt` or `.jpg` or `.gif`?